# Replacing the string " \right)" by "\right)"

Tags: latex

I've got a large string from LaTeX that comes in the form string="\left(3x+1 \right)". In Mathematica. I would like to remove the space at the end of that expression.

The problem is that when I do

```
string=StringReplace[string," \\right)","\\right)"]
```

I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I think this has to do with the \r command in Mathematica. Any ideas on how to avoid Mathematica recognizing that as a command and replacing it only as a string?

Comment: To prevent "\r" to be interpreted as "carriage return" character, you need to double the back slash "\\r"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string = "\left(3x+1 \right)";
string = StringReplace[string, " \r" -> "\\r"]
```

Comment: Wonderful! That worked! Thank you!